# Invalid type argument with R and KKNN:

Tags: r, knn

I have a problem with KKNN training, here is my code, and the files are attached, the problem shows up when I try to create the confusion Matrix:

Error in! All.equal (nrow (data), ncol (data)): invalid type argument

The needed files are [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/18YKZusB3Ey25M0f8OJoeQcL1Brx9uAtM?usp=sharing)

```
library(kknn)
library(caret)

headers = c("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6", "col7", "type")
testData0<-read.table("ecoli-0-1-3-7_vs_2-6-5-1tst.csv", sep = ",", header = FALSE, dec = ".")
names(testData0) <- headers

#------------------original data---------------------------
trainData_org0<-read.table("ecoli-0-1-3-7_vs_2-6-5-1tra.csv", sep = ",", header = FALSE, dec = ".")
names(trainData_org0) <- headers
kknn_org0 <- train.kknn(type ~ ., data = trainData_org0, kmax = 9)
testpred_org0 <- predict(kknn_org0, newdata = testData0[,-8])
accuracy_org0 <- mean(testData0$type == testpred_org0)
confusionMatrix_org0 <- confusionMatrix(table(testpred_org0, testData0$type ))
```

Answer (score 1):

For a classification problem, you should convert your outcome (the column `type` in your data frame) to factor. Here some example code with your data:

```
#since you are run a classification, your outcome should be a factor
#convert "type" to a factor
testData0$type <- as.factor(testData0$type)
trainData_org0$type <- as.factor(trainData_org0$type)


# model fitting------------------------------------------------------

kknn_org0 <- train.kknn(type ~ ., data = trainData_org0,kmax = 9)
testpred_org0 <- predict(kknn_org0, newdata = testData0[,-8])
accuracy_org0 <- mean(testData0$type == testpred_org0)
?confusionMatrix
#confusionMatrix(), takes as first input the predicted values and second input the 
reference values
confusionMatrix_org0 <- confusionMatrix(testpred_org0, testData0$type)#dont't need 
'table(...)'
```